# How can I pass an object from a DataSource to a function from a Kendo DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a DataSource :

```
var ds_IMMAT = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read : {
            url: '<%= Url.Action("GetVehiculesSurSiteAttente", "Entrees_Sorties")%>'
        }
    }
})
```

GetVehiculesSurSiteAttente is defined in a controller of my ASP project. This is working correctly. I get a list of object.

Then I have a KendoDropDownList :

```
$("#Cb_Immat_Window").width(135).kendoDropDownList({
    text: "Aucune donnée",
    index: 0,
    dataSource: ds_IMMAT,
    dataTextField: "Immat_Tracteur",
});
```

I just have to use the name of the variable of the object I want to display with "dataTextField".
My question is the following : How can I pass the entire object that is selected in the DropDownList to a function ? (I want to use the change event of the DropDownList to launch the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) event, use [`this.dataItem()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-dataItem) and you'll have the whole selected object:

```
change: function() {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem();
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/adeKU)